# MySQL Syntax error : "<table_name> is not valid at this position, expecting the name of an existing table". Table already exists

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Version : mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for macos10.13 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

[image]

`groups` table exists in the selected database as shown above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GROUPS` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) since MySQL 8.0.2. In this case you have to escape the table name with backticks. So you have to use the following `INSERT INTO` command:

```
INSERT INTO `groups` (column_name) VALUES (column_value)
```